# Javascript: Opacity of togglebar inherited by navicon

Tags: javascript, css, inheritance

I'm using a javascript [plugin](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pure-javascriptcss-sliding-drawer-menu-bpendrawer/) for a sliding menu. The problem is when I change the opacity of the togglebar(.bpen-drawer), the navicon(.bpen-toggle-pad) inherits it even though i specified a different opacity for the navicon. I've tried `!important` on the navicon but it doesn't work. How can I bypass this inheritance then?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv8znkx3/) with javascript and css.

Comment: Please, provide a fully workable Fiddle so it can be tested and changed.

Comment: Please add some `html` to your Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, my html wasn't being accepted for some reason. but thanks, as pointed out in the previous question of this nature, i used background: rgba on the parent and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

No. That won't work even you set `!important`. If an element has opacity property then it will display based on opacity value. By default all child's are on opacity 1. So if you change opacity value on a child then that child will hide based on that opacity.

So here solution is, you have to change the HTML accordingly or you have to handle this by using js/jQuery